# Is 90 degree image rotation with graphicsmagick or imagemagick lossless

Tags: imagemagick, image-rotation, graphicsmagick

Is the 90 degree image rotation with graphicsmagick or imagemagick always lossless?

E.g. when doing

```
gm convert -rotate 90 img.img rot90.img.img
gm convert -rotate -90 rot90.img.img back.img
```

will img.img and back.img be equal?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.img` files.  If that's a lossless format, then I'd imagine / hope that you'd lose no information in this process.  But if the format is e.g. JPEG, then you'd almost certainly have slight variations at the end.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks for your contribution! Suffix `img` was not meant to denote a certain image file type but rather to stand for all possible image formats.

Comment: Just found article https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/lossless-rotation.html which talks about EXIF orientation and virtual rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this depends more on the particular image format you're using, rather than the internals of Image/GraphicsMagick (assuming they're competently written).

With a raw format (e.g. BMP), there should be no reason for this not to be completely identical.

With a lossless format, it's possible there may be some subtle variations due to numerical precision.

With a lossy format (e.g. JPEG), it's almost certain there will be differences.  In the case of JPEG for example, the compression of each 8x8 block is affected by the block to its left - if you rotate the image then that spatial relationship will change.

Comment: Also, some formats such as `PNG` embed the date and time of creation, so although your image pixels may be bit-for-bit identical, the meta-data may make the files different as far as `cmp` or `diff` are concerned and therefore *”not equal”* per your question.

Comment: *"the compression of each 8x8 block is affected by the block to its left"* The final compression, perhaps, but not the quantization, which is where the loss occurs. It is possible to rotate a JPEG 90° clockwise without loss, and if both dimensions are a multiple of 8 other lossless rotations are possible.

Comment: **JPEG rotation is lossless...** *if performed intelligently.* So, ImageMagick is right out. [The `jpegtran` command is typically what you're looking for here.](https://jpegclub.org) For example, `jpegtran -rotate 90 input.jpg output.jpg` losslessly rotates `input.jpg` by 90° clockwise to `output.jpg`. Interestingly, it's *not* just rotations that can be performed losslessly; it's also rescalings by a ratio "M/N with all M from 1 to 16, where N is the source DCT size, which is 8 for baseline JPEG." Fascinating stuff, frankly.